# release multiple resources at once by a semaphore on Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, semaphore

Seems Posix semaphores don't allow releasing multiple resources at once: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_post.3.html

Is there any other way on Linux?

condition variable is not an option as I need to release a specific number of resources, not all of them

Comment: why would you need to?

Comment: @user253751 performance. waking up a thread is costly. other platforms that I benchmarked, I see quite a difference between releasing multiple resources at once and releasing them one by one. I assume the cost of multiple system calls takes a part, but also there may be an optimisation in the kernel for waking up multiple threads

Comment: [`semop`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/semop.2.html) seems to allow one to specify an array of System V semaphore operations. I have no idea about how POSIX and System V semaphores are linked (if they are).

Comment: Ordinarily, I would suggest `pthread_cond_broadcast` except for your comment. How about looping on `pthread_cond_signal`? But, in either case, you can't control _which_ threads are released. I might suggest a modified version of a ticket lock: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ticket_lock I think you may have to specify the exact conditions/state and what you want. If a released thread loops and rewaits, it could grab the subsequent release meant for another thread. IIRC, the linux kernel, for spinlocks, implemented a queue of waiters, so it implemented fairness.